# PHP Delete an Item from the DB using a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a `while` loop that loops all withdraws from the Database. The thing is that on dashboard it has an accept and decline options and for decline I'll change confirmed from `0` to `1`. But in the while loop (*when clicked*) it performs for all entries, so it changes all of them to `1` instead of just the provided `id`:

```
$get_iteme = $connect->query(
    "SELECT id,username,pmacc,quantity,datew
     FROM withdraws 
     WHERE confirmed = 0 ORDER BY id
");
$row_depo = $get_iteme->num_rows;

if($row_depo) {
    while($item_fetch = $get_iteme->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $item_fetch['id'];
        echo '
            <div class="comment-body">
                <div class="user-img">
                    <img src="modules/dashboard/plugins/images/users/pawandeep.jpg" alt="user" class="img-circle">
                </div>
                <div class="mail-contnet">
                    <h5>Test user</h5><span class="time">'.$item_fetch['datew'].'</span>
                    <br/><span class="mail-desc">PERFECT MONEY ACCOUNT : '.$item_fetch['pmacc'].'</span>
                    <form method="POST"><input type="submit" name="accept" value="Accept" class="btn btn btn-rounded btn-default btn-outline m-r-5">
                        <input type="submit" name="decline" value="Decline" class="btn-rounded btn btn-default btn-outline">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
        if(isset($_POST['accept'])) {
        } else if(isset($_POST['decline'])) {
            $connect->query("UPDATE withdraws SET confirmed = 1 WHERE id = '$id' ") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **PHP Delete an db item from a while loop**? What is your question and what is your title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the id of the entry with a hidden field inside the `<form>` tag so you know which entry should be accepted or declined. So the form should look something like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="the_id_of_your_entry_here" />
    <input type="submit" name="accept" value="Accept" class="...">
    <input type="submit" name="decline" value="Decline" class="...">
</form>
```

Then you can check the `entryId` and react accordingly like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['entryId'], $_POST['accept'])) {
    $stmt = $connect->prepare('UPDATE withdraws SET confirmed = 1 WHERE id = ?');
    $stmt->execute(new array($_POST['entryId'])); // or whatever API for prepared statements you are using...
    $stmt->close();
}
```

And you put this code block outside/before the while loop.

Comment: Thanks ! This solved my problem, i completly forgot that i needed to use an outside function of the while loop using an hidden input in the form

Answer (score 1):

The $_POST['decline'] will be sent once and when the PHP code executed will read it as one variable, you need to add the $_POST['decline'] selected items as an array,

Example : 
In the form page the check boxs would be like this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?=$rowid?>">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?=$rowid?>">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?=$rowid?>">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?=$rowid?>">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?=$rowid?>">
<input type="submit" />
```

in the test.php it would be like this :

```
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $item){ // query to delete where item = $item }
```

Answer (score 0):

your query should be like this;

```
$connect->query("UPDATE withdraws SET confirmed = 1 WHERE id = $id ") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
```

remove quotes around id

Comment: how r u checking. Hv u first change everything to 0